# kubectl config use-context deleting eks user

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I'm encountering some really weird behaviour while attempting to switch contexts using `kubectl`.

My config file declares two contexts; one points to an in-house cluster, while the other points to an Amazon EKS cluster.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <..>
    server: <..>
  name: in-house
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <..>
    server: <..>
  name: eks
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: in-house
    user: divesh-in-house
  name: in-house-context
- context:
    cluster: eks
    user: divesh-eks
  name: eks-context
current-context: in-house-context
preferences: {}
users:
- name: divesh-eks
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      args:
      - "token"
      - "-i"
      - "eks"
      env: null
- name: divesh-in-house
  user:
    client-certificate-data: <..>
    client-key-data: <..>
```

I'm also using the `aws-iam-authenticator` to authenticate to the EKS cluster.

My problem is this - as long as I work with the in-house cluster, everything works fine. But, when I execute `kubectl config use-context eks-context`, I observe the following behaviour.

- Any operation I try to perform on the cluster (say, `kubectl get pods -n production`) shows me a `Please enter Username:` prompt. I assumed the `aws-iam-authenticator` should have managed the authentication for me. I can confirm that running the authenticator manually (`aws-iam-authenticator token -i eks`) works fine for me.
- Executing `kubectl config view` omits the `divesh-eks` user, so the output looks like

  ```
  users:
  - name: divesh-eks
    user: {}
  ```
- Switching back to the in-house cluster by xecuting `kubectl config use-context in-house-context` modifies my config file and deletes the `divesh-eks-user`, so the config file now contains

  ```
  users:
  - name: divesh-eks
    user: {}
  ```

My colleagues don't seem to face this problem.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec` portion of that config was added in 1.10 (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/59495)

If you use a version of kubectl prior to that version, it will not recognize the exec plugin (resulting in prompts for credentials), and if you use it to make kubeconfig changes, it will drop the exec field when it persists the changes

Comment: Thank you very much! My client version was ver 1.9.3; updating my client fixed this problem.